# Selenium webdriver C# - Safari browser is not working

Tags: selenium, safari, selenium-webdriver, safari-extension

I am working on Selenium webdriver C# [ Windows M/c]. I installed the latest safari browser and add the selenium webdriver installable to the extension builder and installed it successfully as well.

But even after that, I am not able to send the URL to the browser. The browser is launched successfully, but after that I could nt see any logs generated.

Selenium error msg is:

Failure: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any input on this please.

STACK TRACE as follows:

```
at OpenQA.Selenium.Safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.Start() in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Safari\SafariDriverCommandExecutor.cs:line 78
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Safari.SafariDriver.StartClient() in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Safari\SafariDriver.cs:line 83
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 83
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Safari.SafariDriver..ctor() in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Safari\SafariDriver.cs:line 73
   at Zms.Spin.AutomationLib.Common.Selenium.Driver.Browsers.DesktopSafariBrowser.GetWebDriver() in C:\USERNAME\Selenium\Driver\Browsers\DesktopSafariBrowser.cs:line 59
   at BaseWebpageTest.BeginTest() in C:\USERNAE\Test\BaseWebpageTest.cs:line 195
   at DemoTest.TestDemoAccountCreation() in C:\USERPATH\DemoTest.cs:line 35
```

P.S - Not sure what inputs I have provide as well in this issue. Kindly let me know if you need any specific

Comment: What code are you using? Where is the stack trace?

Comment: Hi Arran,I added the stack trace. The Code is similar as firefox browser just I invoked the Driver and started with my test.

Comment: No extra DLL's are added apart from the default selenium downloads. I generated the safariextnz file, but not sure if that needs to be added in the references.

Comment: What version of Selenium do you have? What version of Safari do you have?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4271 ...as insisted on this page...please downloaded latest Driver versions and check once again :)